# Java Scanner hasNextLine returns false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have several files (actually they are also java source files saved in Eclipse on Ubuntu) which I need to read and process line by line. I've noticed that I cannot read one of the files. The code I am using is as below

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
        builder.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

I was checking beforehand if the file exists. And it does. I can even rename it. But I cannot read a single line. hasNextLine simply returns false. (I even try hasNext).

At the end I take a look at the content of the file and find that there is a different looking character (which was in the comment section of java file). It is the following character.

```
¸
```

When I delete this character, I can read the file normally. However this is not acceptable. What can I do to read the files even with that character in it?

Comment: what are you trying do here? builder.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");?? adding newline why? looks like you are adding another "newline". one empty line???

Comment: To be clear is the character a period? Also how are you retrieving the file.

Comment: that's a ascii extended character (cedilla: U+00B8) and should give no problems; you should check (with an hexeditor) what the preceding byte is; and in any case `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8")`

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: perhaps if you read it as ascii, it errors on the NULL character?

Comment: I don't get that result (I copied the cedilla into a text file and used code similar to what you have, and hasNextLine returned true).  I wonder if there's a disagreement between the file formats?  I.e. the file is UTF-8 but you're telling Java it's something different, or vice versa).

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Can you write your comment as an answer. Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8") solved my problem.

Comment: @CommuSoft that's what I think, but it does not error, the scanner just bails out with no new line

Comment: @NuriTasdemir let me check if we can find a duplicate first, I am sure there are many already

Comment: @bobs_007 I am reading whole file as it is. nextLine gives the line without "\n" and if I basically append them all, I will end up with a single line without any new lines.

Comment: @ajb As I said files are java source files saved in Eclipse and probably they are saved as UTF-8 and also files are produced in Ubuntu. I am reading those on OSX. The interesting part is when I did not add "UTF-8" as GUIDO suggests, it does not give any errors and hasNextLien just returns false. And that character is not even in the first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most probably a character set issue, caused by the fact that the platform you are running your java code uses by default a different set; it is *always* a good practice to specify the expected/needed character set to be used when parsing, and with the Scanner class is just a matter of calling the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) as:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
```

where the second parameter is the character set literal, or even [better](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```